# Android - Multiple ListView inside HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Please, see the Contacts+ app on the store to know what I mean. You have three ListViews that each has the screen width. You can then scroll each one using a HorizontalScrollView. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Use a viewpager and three fragments having listviews in them.

Comment: Please, add your comment as an answer so I can select it :) Thanks.

Comment: I've added the answer, you should mark it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a viewpager with three fragments as tabs using the tabs adapter like this.

The host activity:

```
    public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
      MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);
        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager =
(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
      }
    }
```

The fragment adapter

```
class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  private List<Fragment> fragments;

  public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
  }
  @Override 
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
  }
}
```

A method to get fragments(optional depends on how you would like the usage to be)

```
private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
  List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

  fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
  fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 2")); 
  fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 3"));

  return fList;
```

And your fragment class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
 public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

 public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message)
 {
   MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
   Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
   bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
   f.setArguments(bdl);
   return f;
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
   TextView messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   messageTextView.setText(message);

   return v;
 }
}
```

Please feel free to get back to me if you need more help.